# Non-technical boss wants us to come up with solutions to client problems without consulting the client on specifics

Tags: consulting

I work as a data scientist consultant. My boss has a lead on a pretty big contract on where the client has a prediction problem they haven't been able to solve. Now I know they have a team of roughly 15-20 in house data scientists/analysts. So I wanted more information about what they had already tried etc. so that we can scope our proposed solution properly, but he refuses to engage with the customer on any technical issues and instead want us to just come up with a proof of concept solution that will solve their problem without knowing anything about their technical infrastructure and what approaches they have tried.

Is this normal? Is this a good approach and I'm missing something?

Comment: Hello L1meta and welcome to the Workplace.SE. _Is this normal / is this a good approach_ that's a business decision on which we cannot really comment (not that kind of forum!) Now if your question is actually how to bring your boss around to your point of view, that would make a question we can answer.

Comment: Sometimes it's preferable to have an independent solution and the boss possibly has solid reasons not to allow contact for information. I've made/sold many solutions for companies and Govt divisions which have their own IT teams in this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your boss is not interested in the details of your work. You could argue that he *should*, but it's rare to find such an individual. You will need to explicitly tell him what you already know: if you don't have that information, you will need to *get* that information. Your customer already *has* that information. Make an estimation of how many man-hours it will take you to find out on your own and how long it should take your client to tell you.

The result might be something like "Our client can bring us to their level of knowledge in a 2 hour phonecall, we would need to spend 40 man-hours to do this without contacting the client." Then let your boss decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Plus: if I don't know what the customer has already tried (and why it failed), I run the risk of proposing this exact solution, which won't make a good impression.